# Not subject despite が?

Tags: particle-が, subjects

I've come across the following dialogue:

> 「シグナムはお風呂どうします？」
>
> 「私は今夜はいい。明日の朝にするよ」
>
> 「**お風呂好きが珍しいじゃん**」

An unofficial, but to my mind high-quality translation offered something like

> "That's rare for a bath-lover like you."

for the last the line, and going by context, that's the only right translation I can think of.

However, going by grammar, wouldn't it translate to

> "Bath-lovers are rare."

?

Of course, this statement feels out of place and is also not true (there are plenty of bath-lovers).

My Japanese friend translated it to

> "You are rare."

claiming that お風呂好き would *directly* refer to シグナム.

He interprets が properly (as a subject marker), but it sounds even more wrong.

Assuming that the unofficial translation I provided first is correct, why is が used, rather than something like にとって? Wouldn't you normally use にとって to express those kinda things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A:「お風呂好きが珍しいじゃん」
>   B:「お風呂好きが**お風呂に行｛い｝かないのは/お風呂に入｛はい｝らないのは**珍しいじゃん」

"A" is an abbreviated expression from "B".
In this case, the substantial contents of the phrase itself is omitted.
This kind of abbreviation is frequently used in daily conversations like:

> 1-1 あなたのようなお風呂｛ふろ｝嫌｛ぎら｝いが珍｛めずら｝しいね。
>   2-1 お風呂嫌いが珍しいね。
>   3-1 勉強{べんきょう}嫌いが珍しいね。
>   4-1 お肉｛にく｝好｛ず｝きが変｛へん｝だね or お肉好きがおかしいね。

These abbreviated expressions correspond respectively to the following perfect expressions like:

> 2-1 あなたのようなお風呂嫌いが**お風呂に入るのは**珍しいね。
>   *It is unusual for a person who dislikes a bath like you, to take a bath.*
>   2-2 同上｛どうじょう｝ Same as above
>   3-2 あなたのような勉強嫌いが（**今日｛きょう｝に限｛かぎ｝って一所｛いっしょ｝懸命｛けんめい｝**）**勉強するというのは**珍しいね。
>   *It is unusual for you, who usually don't study, to study (hard only for today)*.
>   4-2 あなたのようなお肉好きが（**今日に限って**）**お肉を残｛のこ｝すのは**変だね/おかしいね。
>   *It is strange for a meat-lover like you to leave the meat behind (only for today)*.

These abbreviated expressions are used more than perfect ones in everyday conversation, and the latter ones are taken even verbose.

After these study, I could say only C is correct but the rest are incorrect among the following attempts shown in your question.

> C: "That's rare for a bath-lover like you."
>   D: "Bath-lovers are rare."
>   E: "You are rare."

I feel sympathy for non-native people studying Japanese, because in addition to frequent abbreviations of subjects in Japanese, there are omissions of such an important part in a sentence like this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I never thought you could omit the topic even if it's a whole sentence. I'll keep it in mind :)